How to use an Azure DevOps form control extension without adding visible UI elements to Work item type definition?
I have developed an Azure DevOps form control extension that validates whether all attached work items (linked items) are in the "Done" state. If any linked work item is not in the "Done" state, the extension displays an error message.
Currently, this functionality is tied to a visible UI element in the form. However, I want to use this extension purely for validation without introducing any visible UI components.
Any guidance or example would be greatly appreciated.

This is the document for adding custom control :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/custom-control?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops
and you can make it hidden from process change as in this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops#hide-a-field-or-custom-control
